# Is there an API can retrieve Dynamics CRM's updating information

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to show some latest dynamics crm updating information, such as rollup 12, in my application. But i'm not sure the API is existed or not. Did you guys resolve this kind of requirements before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you query the organisation entity it will contain the attribute InitialVersion. This will tell you the build number, this page will then allow you to translate that into a rollup http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/08/15/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-and-2011-update-rollup-release-dates-build-numbers-and-collateral.aspx